# How to call EJB 3.0 by external Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

I am learning EJB 3 and trying some simple stuff on it.

I am using eclipse -> Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) with JBOSS AS 7.1.1 (final)

I created a simple EJB project in eclipse with name -> SalutationEJBProj. Under this project created a simple session, stateless Bean.

## code:

```
package com.vipin.bean.session.stateless;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(mappedName="SalutationBean")
public class SalutationBean implements SalutationBeanRemote {

public SalutationBean() {

}

@Override
public String getFormalSalutation(String name) {

    return "Dear" + name;
}

@Override
public String getInfomalSalutation(String name) {

    return "Hi" + name;
}

}
```

## The Remote interface is:

```
package com.vipin.bean.session.stateless;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface SalutationBeanRemote {

public String getFormalSalutation(String name);

public String getInfomalSalutation(String name);
}
```

## I am able to deploy it in Jboss AS 7.1.1 and here is the JNDI bindings output  when i start the jboss:

```
    java:global/SalutationEJBProj/SalutationBean!com.vipin.bean.session.stateless.SalutationBeanRemote
java:app/SalutationEJBProj/SalutationBean!com.vipin.bean.session.stateless.SalutationBeanRemote
java:module/SalutationBean!com.vipin.bean.session.stateless.SalutationBeanRemot
java:jboss/exported/SalutationEJBProj/SalutationBean!com.vipin.bean.session.stateless.SalutationBeanRemote
java:global/SalutationEJBProj/SalutationBean
java:app/SalutationEJBProj/SalutationBean
java:module/SalutationBean
```

Now, i want this ejb to be accessible by an external Servlet, for this I created a dynamic web project with name --> SalutationServletProj

## Here is the code of the simple Servlet:

```
package com.vipin.servlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/SalutationServlet" })
public class SalutationServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
private SalutationBean salutationBean;  // <-- How will this be accessible, this is in a different project, how do we import this?

public SalutationServlet() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}
}
```

My intention is to use @EJB annotation (or any other method) to get the instance of the EJB in the Servlet.

As these two are in different projects, how can i achieve this? I can't use like this in servlet:

```
import com.vipin.bean.session.stateless.SalutationBean
```

1) What are the files from EJB project that i have to copy into servlet project.

2) Will it work as @EJB annotation or do i need to do JNDI lookup? (Because the servlet is remote).

3) Where can i find the classes/libraries generated in jboss?

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be sufficient to only add the `SalutationBeanRemote` into `WEB-INF/classes` of your web project.

Then it should work out if you add the following member to your Servlet:

```
@EJB(lookup="java:global/SalutationEJBProj/SalutationBean")
private SalutationBeanRemote salutationBean;
```

Only the `java:global...` names will work because your servlet is running in another module and application as the EJB.
I am unsure if the `java:jboss/exported...` lookup name works or if it is only for remote clients.

Best regards,
Robert

Comment: Thanks so much for your inputs, i will try. I have one doubt, if you can reply please do. In general, clients need the "classes" for import. How do we generate these classes? Do we need to provide only the interface classes? It is confusing, and searching in google i have not got correct answer.

Comment: With EJB > 3.0 there is no longer a need for generating classes. It is all up to the runtime to do that at runtime. And also in your web application it should be sufficient to have the `SalutationBeanRemote` in WEB-INF/classes. The AppServer will dynamically generate proxies.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If we are having standalone client, in that case don't we need the class which implements the interface (whether proxy object). Thanks for your help in this.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary. The client runtime should dynamically create the classes upon lookup. The times of rmic should be over.

Comment: Please have a look at this -> http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-remote-ejb-client-tutorial?showall= . The standalone client is importing the interface as well as the class implementing the remote interface. So, i am confused as to how to get these classes.

Comment: I think that they only add the Impl to the client to access the simple class name for the lookup name because it's the default for the ejb name (that is otherwise defined in @Stateless(name=<ejb-name>). Having the bean implementation on client side does not make any sense at all. And with the older EJB 2 beans generated classes were named xxx_Stub etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your inputs. I am wondering in general, how do we provide the interfaces to the remote client. How does remote get these interfaces to connect to ejb? I read online, and most of the times, it is simple "hellow world" kind of programs. So, in real life application, how will this be taken care of? Please suggest any pointers if you have. Best regards

Comment: Well, that's a problem of remote EJBs in general if you want to simply lookup the interface and invoke methods. You always have to distribute the interface.

Comment: An alternative is to expose the EJBs remote interface as a WebService or as a RESTful endpoint. Then you could access the EJB via SOAP over HTTP or simple HTTP calls. But a client without an interface will then have to construct these requests himself.

Comment: thanks so much for your help in understanding this. appreciate a lot. Best regards